# Automate sum in array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I will try to explain the problem that I have with this code.

This script works well to up to three persons ($numRows = 3).

```
$z=0;
$i=0;
$x=0;

do {
    $total[] = (
        ${'contaH'.$z}[$i+0]*$final[$x+0]+
        ${'contaH'.$z}[$i+1]*$final[$x+1]+
        ${'contaH'.$z}[$i+2]*$final[$x+2]
    );
    $z++;
} while ($z<$numRows); //3
```

But if I have only four persons ($numRows = 4), I need something like this:

```
$z=0;
$i=0;
$x=0;

do {
    $total[] = (
        ${'contaH'.$z}[$i+0]*$final[$x+0]+
        ${'contaH'.$z}[$i+1]*$final[$x+1]+
        ${'contaH'.$z}[$i+2]*$final[$x+2]+
        ${'contaH'.$z}[$i+3]*$final[$x+3]
        // if they are 5 persons ($numRows=5), here, should exists another row
    );
    $z++;
} while ($z<$numRows); //4
```

So the problem is to automate these changes in relation of $numRows.

Here is a demo of matrix algebra:

[image]

The only thing that I want is put my code dynamically in a function of number of persons.

```
A   |  B |  C |  D
Person1
Person2
Person3
Person4
...
```

What can be different in my case is just the number of persons.

More information [here](http://kniaz.net/software/AHP.aspx).

Comment: your Question is totally unclear. please re write your question

Comment: Please describe the problem in more general terms, trying to figure out what you want to do from a piece of overcomplicated code isn't easy. What's your data structure? Do you have several variables `$contaH0`, `$contaH1` etc? Why aren't you using arrays instead?

Comment: there is no problem with the code above. The only thing that i want to implement is a variable number of sum rows. if number of $numRows are 3, so must have three sums for each loop, if 4, must have four sums, if 5, must have 5 sums. What must change is the number of sums in function of $numRows

Comment: Still, please state what you want to accomplish. The code you are posting is... strange, to say the least.

Comment: `$total[] = ()` should have a variable number of sums.  `$total[] = (1), $total[] = (1+1), $total[] = (1+1+1), $total[] = (1+1+1+1), $total[] = (1+1+1+1+1)`. The number of sums change in function of `$numRows `. i can't be more clear :S

Comment: That's not what I'm asking -- what are you trying to accomplish? Why would you want `total[2] = 1 + 1 + 1` if just using `3` will work fine? If you want to sum all the values in that array, then, why not just use, you know, math? (`$sum = $n * ($n + 1) / 2`)

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera, more details in my question about matrix algebra.

Comment: Closer. Word of advice: this question should have been asked as "how can I use multidimensional arrays for matrix calculations in Perl?" and everything would have been much easier. I'll try to answer your question.

Comment: I'm also curious why it's tagged PHP when the code is valid Perl not PHP? Did you mean to get the answer in PHP or Perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$z=0;
$i=0;
$x=0;
$numRows = 5;

do{
    $currentSum = 0;
    for($c = 0; $c < $numRows; $c++){
        $currentSum += (${'contaH'.$z}[$i+$c] * $final[$x+$c]);
    }
    $total[] = $currentSum;
    $z++;
}while($z < $numRows);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$subtotal = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $numRows; $i++) {
   $subtotal += ${'contaH'.$z}[$i] * $final[$i];
}
$total[] = $subtotal;
```

Comment: thanks again. the output will be  `( [0] => 313.76656746 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 ) [1] => 0 )`. And the correct should be something like this : `( [0] => 0.320670055732 [1] => 0.324886219083 [2] => 0.19494002706 [3] => 0.159503698125 ) `thanks for the effort

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the [Math_Matrix](https://pear.php.net/package/Math_Matrix) library which will help you do all sorts of matrix arithmetic.

The following code, however, automates your solution:

```
function mat_mult($matrix, $vector) {
    $result = array();
    $matrixWidth = count($matrix[0]);
    for ($z = 0; $z < $matrixWidth; $z++) {
        $value = 0;
        for ($y = 0; $y < $matrixWidth; $y++) {
            $value += $matrix[$z][$y]*$vector[$y];
        }
        $result[] = $value;
    }
    return $result;
}

$matrix = array(
    array(1, 1/3.0, 2, 4),
    array(3, 1, 5, 3),
    array(1/2.0, 1/5.0, 1, 1/3.0),
    array(1/4.0, 1/3.0, 3, 1)
);
$vector = array(0.26, 0.50, 0.09, 0.16);

$v2 = mat_mult($matrix, $vector);

print_r($v2);
```

Also, to tie it more into your existing matrix structure:

```
$matrix = array();
for ($z = 0; $z < $numRows; $z++) {
    $matrix[] = ${'contaH'.$z};
}
```